# Получение индекса первого not null элемента массива

Tags: java

Есть какой-нибудь красивый способ получения индекса первого not null элемента массива? Да, можно написать

```
int index;
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
   if (arr[i] != null) {
       index = i;
       break;
   }
}
```

но, может, есть какой-нибудь более красивый способ для этого? Например, для получения первого not null элемента массива есть метод `ObjectUtils.firstNonNull`, может, есть что-то похожее и для получения индекса?

Comment: а этот код точно работает? А если там примитив? Поэтому задача интереснее становится)

Comment: @pavel, ну, у меня изначально был массив строк)

Comment: А чем не устраивает такой метод?

Comment: @pavel если массив примитивов, то там не будет null-ов

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Можно написать цикл чуть короче:

```
int index = 0;
while (index < arr.length && arr[index] == null)
    ++index;
```

Или даже:

```
int index = -1;
while (++index < arr.length && arr[index] == null) {}
```

Или вот вариант с `for` (спасибо @Qwertiy!):

```
int index;
for (index = 0; index < arr.length && arr[index] == null; ++index);
```

Также можно написать свой метод для этого, использующий любой из способов выше, либо вот так ([Ideone](https://ideone.com/YKrTqw)):

```
static <T> int firstNotNullIndex(T[] arr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i)
        if (arr[i] != null)
            return i;

    // или `return -1`
    return arr.length;
}
```

Comment: `int index = 0;
for (; index < arr.length && arr[index] == null; ++index);`

Comment: @Qwertiy, да, спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Может так (java 8, для String)?:

```
Arrays.asList(array).indexOf(Arrays.stream(array).filter(Objects::nonNull).findFirst().get())
```

Comment: Это будет индекс или значение?

Comment: @Qweriy Это будет индекс.

Comment: А, понял. Там сначала элемент ищется, а потом его индекс. Невнимательно читаю.

Answer (score 0):

По-моему, вот самое изящное решение (благодаря помощи англоязычного SO):

```
int titleIndex = IntStream.range(0, arr.length)
                                    .filter(i -> arr[i] != null)
                                    .findFirst().getAsInt();
```

Comment: Изящное синтаксически? Если раскрыть кишки `IntStream` боюсь мы не обрадуемся

Comment: @Barmaley, ну да, видимо, изящное только синтактически...(